# If user inputs text in cell then return user name and date in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Help, In shared sheet, If user adds text in cell, then click button to return user name and date in another cell.
Example, cell B3 = Complete, then cell C3 returns John Smith 14/04/19

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No need for VBA. Try:

```
=IF(B6="Complete", "User Name " & TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy"),"")
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Great idea, thanks for advice! Will probably need vba so I can keep ‘answer’ dialogue open and not restrict to certain comments.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information might be helpful. I'm going to assume that the layout of the sheet is as follows. You'll need some way of specifying who the current user is, and in this example I have used cell A2.

[image]

If the layout isn't as shown, you will need to edit the code accordingly.

```
Sub date_user()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

With Application.ActiveSheet
    Name = .Range("A2").Value
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B3:B" & lastrow)
End With

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 Then
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
           cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Name & " " & Format(Now(), "MMM-DD-YYYY")
        End If
    End If
Next     
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, will give this a go! I was hoping that user name will be taken from computer user ID, but failing that could try taking from a list

Comment: Ah. To find the user that the PC is assigned to, replace the line Name = .Range("A2").Value with Name = Environ$("username"). If this affects the layout of your sheet, you will need to edit the code accordingly.